# Get 'data-id' property value via JQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML code (I'm using Bootstrap Twitter Modal):

```
 <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='g' data-id=1>Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And the following JQuery code:

```
   <script>
              $('#g').click(function () {
                  alert($(this).data("id"));
              });
   </script>
```

I want that onclick the link, after the bootstrap modal will open, there will be alrt with the 'data-modal' value.

I tried the code above and it didn't work.

My question is how can I fix it? (I'm pretty new with JQuery...)

Comment: Did you add the script at the bottom, after the elements are loaded in the DOM? You should quote the attribute -> `data-id="1"`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6eJP6/

Answer (score 0):

You should place it inside `$(document).ready(function (){});`

See [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for details.